Access Token Expiration
I am writing a code to hit 3rd party integration system from salesforce. They have their api where they are using username password flow to authenticate while salesforce hits their system for first time and sends us a access token along with expires_in field that will contain seconds in which access token will expire. Once access token is expired we have to call again but this time request for refresh token. So I am unable to store expires_in for a single user session since its intializing to zero everytime apex code is run.Let me know if there is a way to maintain variable value for a user session or if there is any other workaround for this case.

Salesforce doesn't have a concept that's like ASP / .Net / PHP / etc "session variables", where you can store data for a user session. Instead, you need to preserve data in the database, using one of the many different solutions that Salesforce has. This could be Custom Settings, Custom Metadata, Platform Cache, Named Credentials, a Custom Field on the User record, etc.
